# How to proof $\frac{I_{m+1} I_{m} + I_m I_{m-1}}{2} \geq I_{m+1} I_{m-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, upper-lower-bounds

Let
$$ I_m=\int_0^\infty (1+s)^m \, {\rm e}^{-ns} \, {\rm d}s \, .$$

I've been thinking some time on the following inequality
$$I_{m} \left( I_{m+1} + I_{m-1} \right) \geq 2 \, I_{m+1} I_{m-1}$$
or in somewhat interesting parallel circuit fashion
$$\frac{1}{I_{m+1}} + \frac{1}{I_{m-1}} \geq \frac{2}{I_m} \, .$$
Is there any clever way to tackle it?

It also looks somewhat like AMGM
$$I_{m+1}^2 + I_{m-1}^2 \geq 2 \, I_{m+1}I_{m-1}$$
in a sense, where one $I_{m+1}$ and $I_{m-1}$ on the LHS is replaced by $I_m$.

$I_m$ is monotonically increasing in $m$ and log-convex (i.e. $I_{m+1} I_{m-1} \geq I_m^2$, without proof though).

It seems to be a rather tight inequality, since e.g. 
$$I_{m+1} I_m + I_m I_{m-1} \geq I_{m+\frac{1}{2}}^2 + I_{m-\frac{1}{2}}^2 \geq 2 \, I_{m+\frac{1}{2}} I_{m-\frac{1}{2}} \leq 2 \, I_{m+1} I_{m-1}$$
or
$$I_m \, \frac{I_{m+1} + I_{m-1}}{2} \geq I_m^2 \leq I_{m+1} I_{m-1} \, .$$

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment.*

After marty cohen's answer, I think that we can prove it that it holds even for $m=n$.
$$I_m=\int_0^\infty (1+s)^m \, {\rm e}^{-ns} \, ds=e^n E_{-m}(n)=\frac{e^n}{n^{m+1}} \Gamma (m+1,n)\qquad \text{if}\qquad \Re(n)>0$$

Now, considering
$$f(m)=I_{m} \left( I_{m+1} + I_{m-1} \right) - 2 \, I_{m+1} I_{m-1}$$
$$e^{-2 n} n^{2 m+3}f(m)=n \Gamma (m,n) (n \Gamma (m+1,n)-2 \Gamma (m+2,n))+\Gamma (m+1,n) \Gamma (m+2,n)\tag 1$$

If $m=n$ and simplifying,
$$f(n)=\frac{2 n+1}{n^3}-\frac{e^{2 n} } {n^{2 n+1} }\,  \Gamma (n,n)^2$$ which is always positive.

Comment: Did you use $$\Gamma(n,n) \leq n^{n-\frac{1}{2}} {\rm e}^{-n} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \, ?$$ or how did you estimate the Gamma function at the end?

Comment: @Diger : I used it based on what is given in https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11#v

Comment: Well ok. But as far as I see it they just give the asymptotic series, while for the estimate you need a bound as in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I will show that
the inequality
is true for
$m$ large compared to $n$.

$\begin{array}\\
I_m
&=\int_0^\infty (1+s)^m e^{-ns}ds\\
&=\int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^m{m\choose k}s^k e^{-ns}ds\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m{m \choose k}\int_0^\infty s^k e^{-ns}ds\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m{m \choose k}\frac{k!}{n^{k+1}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{m!}{(m-k)!n^{k+1}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{m!}{k!n^{m-k+1}}\\
&=\frac{m!}{n^{m+1}}\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{n^k}{k!}\\
&<\frac{m!}{n^{m+1}}e^n
\\
\end{array}
$

If we treat this
as an equality,
and it is close
for $m >> n$,
then
$\frac1{I_m}
\approx \frac{n^{m+1}}{m!e^n}
$
so that
$\frac{1}{I_{m+1}} + \frac{1}{I_{m-1}} \geq \frac{2}{I_m}
$
becomes
$ \frac{n^{m+2}}{(m+1)!e^{n}}+ \frac{n^{m}}{(m-1)!e^n} \geq \frac{2n^{m+1}}{m!e^n}
$

Dividing by
$\frac{n^m}{(m-1)!e^n}
$
this becomes
$ \frac{n^2}{m(m+1)}+ 1 \geq \frac{2n}{m}
$
which is certainly true
for $m \ge 2n$.

Comment: Thanks, but ironically I'm interested in the case $m\leq n$.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on marty cohen's answer, notice the recurrence
\begin{align*}
I_{m+1} = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{m+1}{n}I_m
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
I_{m-1} = - \frac{1}{m} +\frac{n}{m}I_m
\end{align*}
Substituting this into the desired inequality,
\begin{align*}
I_m\left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{m+1}{n}I_m - \frac{1}{m} + \frac{n}{m}I_m \right) \ge 2\left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{m+1}{n}I_m\right)\left(- \frac{1}{m} + \frac{n}{m}I_m\right)
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
I_m \ge \frac{\sqrt{(m - n - 2)^2 + 8m} + 3(n - m) - 2}{2[(m+1-n)^2 - (m+1)]}
\end{align*}
From here, you might try induction on $m, n$.